# Error with Speaker Recognition API: "Resource or path can't be found."

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to run the enroll profile code of speaker recognition API using Jupyter Python.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
{ "error": { "code": "NotFound", "message": "Resource or path can't be found." } }
```

Here is the code:

```
#Loading .wav file   
     w = wave.open("Harshil_recording_final.wav", "rb")
     binary_data = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
#User Enrollment
    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '*subscription-key*',
    }

    params = urllib.urlencode({
        # Request parameters
        'identificationProfileId':user1,
        'shortAudio': 'true',
    })

    body = w

    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
        conn.request("POST",  "/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/{identificationProfileId}/enroll?%s" % params, str(body), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        print(data)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

identificationProfileId is part of the URL path, not a query parameter.  You should do the following instead:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({
        # Request parameters
        'shortAudio': 'true',
    })
...
conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/{0}/enroll?{1}".format(user1, params), body, headers)
```

Comment: I realized my mistake. thanks but get the following response:

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid Audio Format: Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"
  }
}

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question, but you'll want to send the raw audio, including the RIFF headers.  In your code snippet you're sending 'naked' audio frames.  Since you're sending the entire .wav file anyway, you can just set `body = open('test.wav', 'rb')`

Comment: I did try it , the error is solved but returns empty data rather what actually should be returned is the location url

Comment: The location URL is in a response header, not the body. `response.info().getheader('Operation-Location').`

Comment: Or, rather, `response.getheader('operation-location')`